# Youtube Playlist

Tags: mediaplayer

Has anyone figured how to play playlist from youtube?

I know I can play single video if I visit youtube directly in Internet Explorer, but what about playlist. Because I have some pretty music on my YT account and would love to listen them on my phone.

Comment: In the default player this can't be done just yet. I'll look around to see if there is an app that supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Metrotube app - 5 out 5 stars!